# Getting Distinct Data from two Columns SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get the distinct data from two columns in the same table.

Table 1:

```
***ID Address          City***
   01 Test Street      Springdale
   01 Main Street      Springdale
   01 Pass Dr.         New Town
   01 Main Street      New Town
```

I want the results to look like this;

```
***Address          City***
   Test Street      Springdale
   Main Street      New Town
   Pass Dr.
```

Currently I have this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Address
    FROM Table1
    WHERE ID = 01
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT City
    FROM Table1
    WHERE ID = 01
```

But what I get in return is:

```
***Address***
Test Street      
Main Street      
Pass Dr. 
Springdale
New Town
```

Comment: Your desired output looks strange for a few reasons.  1) Why doesn't `Pass Dr.` have a value for the `City` column? 2) It seems like you are arbitrarily choosing a city to display for `Main Street`.  Is this true?

Comment: What you might want is a query that returns multiple result sets rather than trying to put both addresses and cities in the same result set.

Comment: Why would you *ever* want your output to look like that? That's atrocious! Your starting table data looks fine to me. Each city and address pair should be unique, but you should take the entire row into consideration, not each column individually. **EDIT: *Unless* you are no longer associating the columns with each other.

Comment: I'm tying to use this in a stored procedure that will give me distinct values for the Address and City so that I can put those values into two separate drop down lists.

Comment: @user3653252 these are then two separate result sets - use 2 select statements in your stored procedure. You can still read them both in code (I assume .NET) using [SqlDataReader.NextResult()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.nextresult(v=vs.110).aspx). Returning them as one table just makes things messy and harder to process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using nested CTEs as follows will produce the result set required in the OP:

```
;WITH CTE_Address AS 
(
   SELECT DISTINCT Address
   FROM #T
), CTE_Address_rn AS
(
   SELECT Address, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Address) AS rn
   FROM CTE_Address
), CTE_City AS
(
   SELECT DISTINCT City
   FROM #T 
), CTE_City_rn AS
(
   SELECT City, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY City) AS rn
   FROM CTE_City
)
SELECT a.Address, c.City
FROM CTE_Address_rn AS a
LEFT JOIN CTE_City_rn AS c ON a.rn = c.rn
```

The basic idea is to produce two separate result sets containing distinct Addresses and Cities and join these by `ROW_NUMBER`.

[SQL Fiddle Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/708fb/2)

P.S. The above answer is based on the assumption that the OP just wants distinct Address and City values put into a single table, disassociated from each other.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are only ever selecting one column.  The union just puts two data sets together and deupes.  So the first one reads distinct address and the second distinct city and then retuns as one list.

You should really return these as two different data sets or use two different procs.  You can do the former just be getting rid of your UNION.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ;WITH CTE_Address AS 
 (
    SELECT ID, Street_Address, DENSE_RANK () over (Order by Street_Address) as Denserank_Street
    FROM The_Table
 ),
 CTE_City AS
 (
   SELECT ID, City_Name, DENSE_RANK () over (Order by City_Name) as Denserank_City
   FROM The_Table 
 )

 SELECT a.Address, c.City
 FROM CTE_Address AS A
 INNER JOIN CTE_City AS C ON A.ID = C.ID

 P.S. Without the ID column, the JOIN statement will give wrong match between City and Address.
```